# Error When Show test in label

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I use BMPlayer.
When use func :

```
bmPlayerView.playTimeDidChange = { (currentTime: TimeInterval, totalTime: TimeInterval) in
            //            print("playTimeDidChange currentTime: \(currentTime) totalTime: \(totalTime)")
            self.subtitleShow(currentTime: currentTime)
        }
```

for show Subtitle in Label.

```
 func subtitleShow(currentTime: TimeInterval){

let millisecond = Int(currentTime * 1000)

                for i in (clip.subtitle?.enDialog)!{
                    if i.start <= millisecond && i.end >= millisecond {
                            subtitleLabel.text = i.text
                            return
                        }

                    }

            }
```

But Show Error:

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Do you read Error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message simply tells you to update the label on the main thread:

```
bmPlayerView.playTimeDidChange = { (currentTime: TimeInterval, totalTime: TimeInterval) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.subtitleShow(currentTime: currentTime)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the UI, you must do it from the main thread.
You can use this

```
bmPlayerView.playTimeDidChange = { (currentTime: TimeInterval, totalTime: TimeInterval) in
     // print("playTimeDidChange currentTime: \(currentTime) totalTime: \(totalTime)")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] () -> Void in
                    self?.subtitleShow(currentTime: currentTime)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant modify gui from background. For do this you need use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(){
    //code
}
```